# What does 'this' context type void not assignable to type rule mean?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm running some tests in Typescript to see if something I want to make is possible. I need to set the type of 'this' inside of a function to a class; it works, however, I keep getting the error: The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Rule'. Below is the code.

**TLDR**
How can I specify the type of this inside of a stand alone function?

**PS** Maybe there is a better way to do it so I will explain what I am trying to do: What I am trying to do is create a rule class, where I add a function that either returns true or false if it does it returns the notes as well as a status. I do not want the function to have a bunch of parameters. I would like the class to be able to interact with other classes and have access to other data but be stand alone for testing purposes.

```
export class Rule {
    constructor(rule) {
      this.Fx = rule
}
    Fx;
    passNote;
    failNote;
    guest;
    apiData;
    runRule(dev) {
     this.Fx(dev)
    }
}

function apple(this: Rule, dev) {}

const test = new Rule((dev) => dev.pass)
const dev = // large object I am testing with the rule
test.runRule(dev)
 // The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Rule'
```

all I want is intelisence for 'this' when writing the function that I use in the constructor.

Comment: ". I do not want the function to have a bunch of parameters" really? How about passing an object?

Answer (score 3):

You can `.call` apple:

```
 apple.call(new Rule, 'poop');
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish with the `apple` function, but this has to do with the way `this` binding works. I would recommend reading up more on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), but when you call a function normally (like you have in your code), the `this` context refers to the global scope when not in strict mode, and `undefined` when in strict mode. Your TypeScript code likely compiles to JavaScript in strict mode, so the error is trying to tell you that this `undefined` value is not of the type `Rule`. If you want `this` to refer to an instance of the class object, you can assign it to the object and call it through the object binding, rather than directly calling the function:

```
function apple(this: Rule, dev) {}
export class Rule {
    constructor() {}
    Fx;
    passNote;
    failNote;
    guest;
    apiData;
    apple = apple;
};

const rule = new Rule();
rule.apple('test'); // now the this keyword will refer to the Rule object you instantiated
```

Alternatively, you can just pass in the object to the `apple` function as its own argument rather than trying to use `this`. Because of how confusing using the `this` keyword can be when you don't fully understand how it works, I would recommend this approach:

```
const rule = new Rule();
function apple(rule: Rule, dev) {}
apple(rule, 'test');
```